# How do I find the maximum force when one block is held tight against a wall?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics, classical-mechanics

The problem is as follows:

> Two bodies are shown in the figure shown below. These are at rest. It
>   is known that the coefficients of friction between the surfaces in
>   contact are $0.5$ and $0.3$. Find the magnitude of the maximum force
>   $\vec{F}$ in $N$ so that the bodies are at rest. The blocks masses are
>   follows $m=6\,kg$ and you may use $g=9.8\frac{m}{s^2}$.

[image: Sketch of the problem]

The alternatives on my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&147\,N\\
2.&176\,N\\
3.&187\,N\\
4.&206\,N\\
5.&217\,N\\
\end{array}$

For this problem I'm totally lost at. How am I supposed to use the information given. I find it confusing at what are those values of the coefficients refer?. Are these the static and kinetic friction for the surface between $m$ and $3m$?. Or is it the static friction between $m$ and $3m$. If the latter is the case, which is which?. $0.5$ for between $m$ and $3m$ and $0.3$ for the block $3m$ and the floor, or is it viceversa?. Can somebody help me with a FBD for this problem?!!. I really need help with this one.

Comment: I don't see your efforts to solve the issue.

Comment: @Cesareo. I'm sorry about that. I attempted to do it by my own but as I mentioned I got stuck because I didn't know how to proceed with this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

For the small body

$$
-T + \mu_1 m g = 0
$$

For the big body

$$
-\mu_1 m g -\mu_2(m + 3m) g + F =0
$$